# AVAssetReader with streamed H.264 samples

Tags: ios, stream, decode, h.264, rtsp

I'm writing an RTSP/H.264 client. Live555 for parsing the RTSP is great, but using ffmpeg for software decoding is just too slow. I'd like to use AVFoundation to hardware decode the samples. I'm not sure how to do this. My question is, is there any way to get AVFoundation (AVAssetReader?) to decode these samples as they come in and display the feed on-screen?

Answer (score 3):

From now the media sample encoded with H264 comes from memory can't use hardware decode, because iOS doesn't open these interfaces, you can only decode local file or by HTTP Live Streaming. However, there is a possible solution that write every sample into a separate mp4 file, then read it with AVAssetReader, but I didn't try that, maybe speed is a limit.

Comment: Thanks, zhzhy. That was one approach I was considering, but I haven't tried it yet. I'll get back when I do.

Comment: Writing to a mp4 file and hardware decoding it is just us slow (perhaps slower) than libav.  One method I am looking at right now is to create a URL that reads and writes from memory.

Comment: ha, @Cthutu, if you can get one method like you say, that is wonderful!

Comment: I've tried using a custom URL and confirmed I can use it via dataWithContentsOfURL: but despite passing it to AVFoundation, it doesn't use it.  It seems that AVFoundation doesn't use the URL loading system, but rather just supports local files and http.

Comment: We recently found that you can create a url in the file system using standard c file io , and give that url to assetwriter. General consensus is most reads will fail but just keep ignoring errors you will eventurally get good reads.

Answer (score 0):

This may at least get you started

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/FFPlayer-tests

Comment: Use of ffmpeg code in an iOS app has a number of murky legal issues, See the accepted answer to this question for a better iOS 8 approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197169/how-to-decode-a-h-264-frame-on-ios-by-hardware-decoding

Comment: Not really, I don't know were you people get this. using any open source code is risky. FFMPEG is LGPL, translation you can use it compiled as a static lib. mute point really , with IOS 8 software decoding is officially dead.

Comment: If you would like to learn more about the issue, take a look at this article: http://multinc.com/2009/08/24/compatibility-between-the-iphone-app-store-and-the-lgpl/

Comment: 2009 really, I suggest you read what ffmpeg.org has to say on there site.again you take a change with any open source software you use.However that said there are many many apps in the app store that use ffmpeg. As of iOS 8 this will decrease not because of licensing but because software decoding the dominant use case for ffmpeg on IOS is no longer the only game in town.

Comment: Yes, and they are all in violation of the LGPL license provided with ffmpeg. If you really want to read more about it, ffmpeg authors address the issue here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1229 but the bottom line is that GPL and LGPL code is a real gray area when statically linking into iOS apps. One cannot simply ignore this legal issue based on personal opinions.